# How to define zoom button in openlayers API?

Tags: javascript, css, api, openlayers, openstreetmap

How can I remove default *ol-zoom* buttons and define another zoom buttons with different tags and class names in *openlayers* API?

```
<div class="ol-zoom ol-unselectable ol-control">
    <button class="ol-zoom-in" type="button" title="Zoom in">+</button>
    <button class="ol-zoom-out" type="button" title="Zoom out">−</button>
</div>
```

I used this code to set CSS class name for zoom buttons but I dont know why it doesn't work :

```
new ol.control.Zoom({
          className: "my-new-class-name"
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see if you actually added the Zoom control to the map. Instantiating the control itself does not change the OL map. Also, the map has a default zoom control instance. If you called `addControl` on the map, you might have ended up with two zoom controls being placed above each other.

You can give your control as a option to the map initialization. If you do not want to list all other controls manually, just use [ol.control.defaults](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.control.html) with the option `zoom: false`. It omits the zoom control but adds the default attribution and rotation controls.

You could even give your options directly to the ol.control.defaults:

```
ol.control.defaults({
    zoomOptions: {
        className: "ol-zoom my-new-class-name"
    }
})
```

Secondly, setting the className is not additive, it replaces the default ol-zoom class. So your control might be added to the DOM, but has no styling and is placed offscreen. You can fix that by adding `ol-zoom` to the className too.

Here is a working example:

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    zoom: false
  }).extend([
    new ol.control.Zoom({
          className: "ol-zoom my-new-class-name"
        })
  ]),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3,
  })
});
```

```css
.ol-zoom.my-new-class-name {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```